# Can Haskell libraries documentation be ordered by typeclasses and types?

Tags: haskell

We can already have access to [Haskell libraries documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/) that are organized by `modules`. Have any efforts been made to sort them out by `typeclasses` and `types`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Take a look at the indices produced as part of Hackage's Haddock display](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/doc-index-D.html)